# how to compare a string with an integer

Tags: java, for-loop, integer

I have this loop but i dont know why it never check the condition,i thought it might for integer.tostring,please help if you can:

```
   public static void linerSearch(String[] array1, int key){
        int size = array1.length;
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            if(array1[i] == Integer.toString(key)){ // < -- This line
                System.out.println("The node is already in the list");
            }
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(array1[i].equals(Integer.toString(key))){
```

with `==` you compare the object references and not the values. you have to use `equals()`

Answer (score 2):

```
if(Integer.parseInt(array1[i]) == key){
```

Comment: nice alternative possibility

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare contents of strings with `==` you will have to use the `equals()` method:

```
if (array1[i].equals(Integer.toString(key))
```

Comment: you can compare strings with `==` but this is the equality on object references, not content

Comment: You're totally right! I'll modify my post accordingly!